# How to measure Page Load Time?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

is there any way to measure the page load time when we are using the Tor network?
For example, the time between when we put the Yahoo.com into the address bar and press the enter and the time we receive the last data from the network.

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing with this. You can snapshot sites using [Midori](http://midori-browser.org/) (which saves PNGs) or [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). In a bash script, echo the current time before starting the snapshot. The file timestamp tells you when the load completed. The difference is the loading time.

You can use ...

```
NOW=`date +%F_%H-%M-%S
echo "snapshot http://yahoo.com starting $NOW"
torsocks midori -s http://yahoo.com
```

... or ...

```
NOW=`date +%F_%H-%M-%S
echo "snapshot http://yahoo.com starting $NOW"
torsocks wkhtmltopdf http://yahoo.com yahoo.pdf
```